# Angular Directive Still Initializing in Other Views

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have an angular directive which I am using as an attribute. I was messing around and have applied styles to a specific view. The issue is, when I change routes, the styling is still applied. I have an alert div which is present on every view, and the styling applied when it is initialized is carried onto other views. The watchers also remain initialized in subsequent views and are throwing errors when the window is resized. Here is my directive:

```
.directive('fixedHeader', function ($log, Screensize, $timeout, $window, navigationService) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

        if (Screensize.current === 'desktop' && !Screensize.ipad) {

            // On resize, dynamically assign th widths based on td widths
            scope.resizeElements = function () {

                // DOM Selectors and initial element widths
                var alerts = document.querySelector('.ManageOrders .alerts');
                var th = element[0].querySelector('tbody tr:first-child').querySelectorAll('th');
                var thWidth = element[0].querySelector('tbody tr:first-child');
                var tdw = element[0].querySelector('tbody tr:last-child').querySelectorAll('td');
                var tdWidth = element[0].querySelector('tbody tr:last-child').offsetWidth;
                var headerHeight = document.querySelector('.orders-toolbar').offsetHeight + document.querySelector('.title-bar').offsetHeight;
                var header = element[0].querySelector('tbody tr:first-child');
                var tablePadding = element[0].querySelector('.tablePadding');
                var pagination = document.querySelector('.paginationWrapper');
                var filters = document.querySelector('.orders-toolbar');

                // Fixed filter box styling
                filters.style.position = 'fixed';
                filters.style.top = '6.1em';
                filters.style.borderTop = '1em solid #F2F2F2';
                filters.style.width =  tdWidth + 1 + 'px';

                // Alert styling
                $timeout(function() {
                    alerts.style.marginTop = headerHeight + pagination.offsetHeight + header.offsetHeight - 2 + 'px';
                    alerts.style.width = tdWidth + 'px';
                    alerts.style.marginLeft = 'auto';
                    alerts.style.marginRight = 'auto';
                });

                // Remove main content padding to accomodate alerts
                document.querySelector('.ManageOrders .main-content').style.paddingTop = 0;

                // Add padding to display first result beneath fixed header
                // tablePadding.style.height = document.querySelector('.orders-toolbar').offsetHeight + document.querySelector('.paginationWrapper').offsetHeight + header.offsetHeight - 13 + 'px';

                // Fixed Pagination styling
                pagination.style.position = 'fixed';
                pagination.style.top = (headerHeight - 1 + 'px');
                pagination.style.width = tdWidth + 1 + 'px';
                pagination.style.backgroundColor = '#F2F2F2';
                pagination.style.zIndex = '500';

                // Fixed Header styling
                header.style.position = 'fixed';
                header.style.top = (headerHeight + pagination.offsetHeight - 2 + 'px');
                header.style.zIndex = '500';
                thWidth.style.width = tdWidth + 'px';

                // Assign appropriate widths to th elements
                for (var i=0;i<th.length;i++) {
                    if (tdw[i]!==undefined) {
                        th[i].style.maxWidth = tdw[i].offsetWidth + 'px';
                        th[i].style.width = tdw[i].offsetWidth + 'px';
                    }
                }
            }

            // Watch for new order load... If no results, re-draw table when there are results (fixed rendering error)
            scope.$watch('model.pageOrderList', function(newV, oldV) {
                if (newV.length>=1 && newV.length!==oldV.length) {
                    scope.resizeElements();
                }
            });

            // Listen for window resize
            angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
                scope.resizeElements();
                scope.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                // Listen for window resize, delay trigger... Fixed issue with element widths not rendering properly in certain situations (e.g. opening and closing console)
                $timeout(function() {
                    scope.resizeElements();
                },100);
            });

            // Initial table render... Two $timeouts to load properly in IE
            $timeout(function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    $(window).trigger('resize');
                    scope.resizeElements();
                });
            });
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you leaving the element with the directive attribute in the view?

Comment: @SimonH No, the element is specific to one view. This attribute / element is not defined anywhere else other than on this view

Comment: I think we will need a plnkr to help you more